# Validation rule error when using picklist

Tags: picklist, validation-rule

I have this validation rule that I created but I am getting an error saying

> Error: Field Pre_Service_Call_Completion_Status__c is a picklist field. Picklist fields are only supported in certain functions.

```
AND( 
    Pre_Service_Call_Completion_Status__c = "Successful - Conversation Happened", 
    ISBLANK(Conversation_Type__c), 
    Task_Status__c = "Complete" 
)
```

basically I want when Call Completion Status field equals "Successful - Conversation Happened" we want "Conversation Type" field to be filled out before task Status equals "Complete"

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all. Picklist fields can only be used in certain functions.

In this case, you need to use `ISPICKVAL(<field api name>, <value to test for>)`. Using `TEXT()` would also work.

See [Using Picklists in Formulas](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/advanced_formulas/picklist_formulas) on trailhead to get a better idea. And as always, referencing [the official documentation for formula operators and functions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5) is a good idea if you need to figure out what something does.